# Detection if user votes before?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am Biulding an mvc asp.net website i want to add polls, i  want to check if the user vote before what can i use:
1. IP : there is the problem of private and public IP
2.Cookie can be deleted
help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reliable way to achieve this is to require your users to authenticate to your site before voting. This way you can store the information that a user has already voted in your database. This way when a user logs in and attempts to vote you will know whether he has already voted or not.

If you allow anonymous users to vote on your site there just is no reliable way to do this.